# How to get the name of all the test methods and functions in a test?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-design, test-automation-framework

I am developing a framework where I need to do the reporting of my tests. I have to do this from scratch with out using junit or testng. I need to create a custom annotation `@Testing` and write a test methods and other methods related to this.

My report should be in the following format:

```
Test name 1 
method 1
..
method n

Test name 2
method 1
..
method n
```

Is this possible to do it with an custom annotation or Is there any work around for this?